# Real timestamp GPS

Tags: android, gps, timestamp

I'm trying to compare the GPS timestamp with the hour of device. When I use location.getTime() the GPS hour is the same hour of the device, I need to know how I can get the real timestamp of the GPS, I can't to trust in the system hour, because the users can change the date/hour manually on device.

Comment: Are you sure that you receives Location from GPS provider? getTime() for GPS must return time from satellite, not from device

Comment: @nnesterov at least in ios the GPS time is modified by the iOS, and is alreday time zone corrected (and uses in the correction what the owner manually setted as system time) . In a smartphone you don't have direct access to the GPS messages which would return the time either in UTC or (less useable in GPS time, which differ from UTC by about 16 leap seconds)

Comment: I do not tested on iOS , but I 'm really sure that I am using GPS provider Location.